# CakePHP 3.0 cake Console error -intl extension missing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working with cakephp 3.0 and my application is working fine. I have already enable intI extension.I'm having problems with the cake console. When I try to run any command like:

```
bin/cake
```

Output is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in     C:\wamp\
www\myapp\config\bootstrap.php on line 38
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\myapp\bin\cake.php:0
PHP   2. include() C:\wamp\www\myapp\bin\cake.php:31
```

PHP version :5.4.16

Thanks in advance,
Kosala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wamp has separate php.ini files for webserver and CLI. So you might have intl enabled for webserver but not for CLI. So locate the relevant php.ini and enable the extension for CLI too.